# Does the potential difference between any point on resistor is same or different?

Tags: voltage

We know that between the ends of the conductors potential difference is maintained if we connect conductor with an energy source like cell or battery.

But does inside the conductor , between any point in conductor and anode end of conductor there is same potential difference as at between two ends of conductor because electronics travel from high potential to low potential and there is energy drop while passing through conductor , so according to this potential should be less at any point inside conductor than compared to anode? Or what actually going on?

Look at it

[image]

**Here potential difference would be less or equal to 5V in 2nd case?** Because 'e-' has traveled half way and loose some of its potential energy!

And if yes , it is low that don't you think different amount of current should flow in resistor at each point as potential energy keep on decreasing reducing efficiency of flow or does electric field remain constant so current is constant but how electric field is constant although potential difference between both points in both cases is difference?

**I can't understand this topic at all please don't mark it downvote as it is the only hope to get answer**

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually split your resistor into multiple resistors in series

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqTbsg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've made the power source 4 V to make the sums easier.

On the R4/7 resistor, obviously the connection points are at 1, 2 and 3 volts.

If we instead consider R4 and R5 together as R2, then R2's midpoint is still at 3 V. Similarly, there are points through R1 that are at 1 V, 2 V and 3 V.

That's how potentiometers are made. A long resistor is tapped by a movable wiper, that makes contact with any point along the length of the resistor.

Comment: I can't get it much sir, please elaborate more in easy way (actually this is completely new topic for me) and also how it answer my doubt that 1 . Does potential difference between two points are same in both case as in diagram I have shown? 2. If not , that according to this current should be different I guess? Please explain  these main doubts in ur answer too. Sorry for taking ur time but I m a newbie

Comment: Your conductor has resistance. Assuming the conductor is consistent the whole length then it is a simple fraction. Half way down your conductor, half the voltage. Quarter the way, quarter the voltage and so on. Only primary school math involved.

Comment: @Kartman , O .. like in mid point of whole resistor,  v would be 2 in ur diagram. , but sir one more doubt doesn't the current get affected as P.D is different between any two points in resistor eg. In my given diagram in 2st case V is quite high compared to 2nd case (let say 1/4 of V) than according to it electrical field between 1st case is stronger than 2nd so there should be imbalance of current (less in case 1 than 2)? I know it is my misconception but please one time clear it.

Comment: Could you spend a little more effort to make your writing a little more understandable. What is ‘ur’? Do you mean ‘err’ as in ‘error’? Anyway, current flows in a loop and is the same at any point in the loop. think of a chain with a 1 tonne load - each link has 1tonne of force on it. If you have any doubt, get yourself some resistors, wire, battery and a multimeter and make Ohms law your friend.

Comment: @Kartman, sorry for that errors. I will try to solve it myself but just help me a little by sharing your knowledge.           First, Does  the electric field is same  between both point in  image 1 and image 2 in my question?               Second,  Does change in electric field change current for a consistent conductor?